# How could such low number of clone troopers fight wars across the galaxy?

Tags: star-wars

According to [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/121846/931), active clone troopers in the GAR (Grand Army of Republic) were in millions. If I draw analogies from the real world, they aren't enough for even planetary wars. China, India, North Korea, Russia and US all have [millions of *active* soldiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_number_of_military_and_paramilitary_personnel) just protecting borders. And, they aren't enough for planetary control as garrison forces.

How could then GAR fight separatist worlds with clone troopers? Even droids aren't needed for this. Just training and equipping hot bloods with weapons could hold off GAR.

What's the catch here? Why didn't Lucas talk in billions or trillions? These are just numbers which couldn't break the plot or anything.

Comment: Good point. Unlike George Lucas, J. K. Rowling at least admitted that she was bad at math.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**With help.**

Although the clones were one of the most visible symbols of the Republic and were critical in Palpatine's overall plan, they weren't the only forces fighting for the Republic. Two other key elements of the Republic's defense were the Judicial Forces and the Planetary Defense Force.

The Judicial Forces were primarily naval forces, suited to patrolling hyperspace routes and trade lanes, or raiding Confederacy shipping. Planetary Defense Forces, naturally enough, were raised by individual worlds in the Republic and were intended for defensive use, but could be deployed on campaign if absolutely necessary.

Because these forces were raised at the local level across the Republic, they were extremely numerous but not very centralized. Their roles were therefore to protect and hold Republic territory while the clones of the Grand Army carried out more vital operations that required greater coordination and concentration of force.

When the Empire was declared, these forces along with the clone army were folded into the new Imperial Army and Navy; many non-clone Imperials were originally Judicial Forces or Planetary Defense troops. The eponymous officer of the *Tarkin* novel (in Canon) and Gilad Pellaeon (in various Legends works) were notable examples of Imperial officers who once fought for the Republic.

It's worth considering, too, that neither side was really interested in large-scale invasions for their own sake. They both believed that if they removed the enemy's leadership, the other systems would more or less fall in line, so they were more concerned about attacking specific, vital targets than in occupying every square kilometer of the other side's planets.

Comment: Good answer, but can you please provide citations? I don't remember `Planetary Defense Forces` being mentioned in any of the movies or TV shows.

Comment: @TimeLord They mainly appear in Canon novels, particularly *Tarkin*, *Thrawn*, and *Bloodline*. Tarkin's family was deeply involved in the Eriadu defense force (and he himself was in the Judicial Forces), so his novel is probably the most in-depth.